# Issue with implementing badges in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am working in ios app in phonegap with pushnotification.i have added the below code in Appdelegate+notification.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    PushPlugin *pushHandler = [self getCommandInstance:@"PushPlugin"];
    [pushHandler didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveNotification");
        // Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
    UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
                appState = application.applicationState;
    }

    if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        PushPlugin *pushHandler = [self getCommandInstance:@"PushPlugin"];
        pushHandler.notificationMessage = userInfo;
        pushHandler.isInline = YES;
        [pushHandler notificationReceived];
    } else {
        //save it for later
        self.launchNotification = userInfo;
    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"] intValue];
}
```

I am using pushNotification.java file for sending push message to our application in that i have mentioned payload.addBadge(1);

So in my app badge gets update onclick of notification Please suggest me how to do it while receiving notification

Comment: Look at the link : http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/ have you implement all stuffs or not. This link for notification in phonegap ios app.

Comment: ya i tried but it is not working,can you please suggest me how to increment while receiving notification in ios native code.And please give me idea how payload.addBadge(1); is setting as 1 in appicon while pushing notification.